# jQuery if img src equals then apply class name each img

Tags: jquery

Basically my img src looks like this and has class name .pic:

```
img/folderA/..
img/folderB/..
img/folderC/..
..
img/folderZ/..
```

and I want add class name each of the img example if imc src equals /folderA/ then add that img class name 'thisisA' etc., i tried something like this but it wont work any help?

```
    $('.pic').each(function(i){
        var imgSrc = this.src;
        if(imgSrc.indexOf('/folderA/')){
            $(this).addClass('thisisA');
        }
            else if(imgSrc.indexOf('/folderB/')){
            $(this).addClass('thisisB');
        }
});
```

Comment: why the downvote? the OP has a problem, made an effort to solve it, posted his code and clearly explained what's the issue..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.pic').each(function(i){
        var imgSrc = this.src;
        if(imgSrc.indexOf('/folderA/') >= 0){
            $(this).addClass('thisisA');
        }
            else if(imgSrc.indexOf('/folderB/') >= 0){
            $(this).addClass('thisisB');
        }
});
```

`indexOf` returns -1 when there's no match, and anything other than 0 is considered "true" by `if`.

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

http://jsfiddle.net/nZCre/1/

```
 $('.pic').each(function(i){
        var imgSrc = this.src;
        if(imgSrc.indexOf('/folderA/') > -1){
            $(this).addClass('thisisA');
        }
            else if(imgSrc.indexOf('/folderB/')){
            $(this).addClass('thisisB');
        }
});​
```

if indexOf returns 0 then it will be false, which is probably what is happening:
`if(0){dosomething()}` will never `dosomething();`

Answer (score 0):

The [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) method returns the position in the string where what you're looking for is. This can cause some weird issues. For example: `'hello'.indexOf('h');` will return 0 because `h` is in the first position (index 0) in the string.

That means that if you tested like this:

```
var str = 'hello';
if(str.indexOf('h')) //indexOf returns 0 which is evaluated as false
  alert('hello');
else
  alert('goodbye');
```

you would always be alerted goodbye even though you are expecting hello.

In order to help with this, `indexOf` returns `-1` if what you are looking for is not found in the string. So you need to check against that instead. So with your code it would be like:

```
$('.pic').each(function(i){
    var imgSrc = this.src;
    if(imgSrc.indexOf('/folderA/') != -1){
        $(this).addClass('thisisA');
    }
    else if(imgSrc.indexOf('/folderB/') != -1){
        $(this).addClass('thisisB');
    }
});
```